# iOS – Upload in background at certain times

Tags: ios

We have an iOS app which is collecting some data (location, accelerometer, etc.) in the background. We would like to upload this data to our server so our server can do some analysis on the data; we would like to batch all the collected data and upload it to our servers periodically, perhaps every 12 or so hours (so ~2 times a day).

After looking around I've seen lots of recommendations:

- **Background Fetch:** This appears to be limited to downloads and also isn't guaranteed execution
- **Silent (Push) Notification:** This also appears to be not guaranteed, especially when the app is terminated. Also setting up our server to auth with APNS and send notifications seems excessive for such a simple 'problem'.
- **Continuing Upload:** Specifically when the app is entering the background. This is a good first step, but because we want to batch data doesn't solve the upload on schedule problem.

I was considering testing if we could use `applicationSignificantTimeChange` to kickoff an upload at midnight, but that seems to only trigger when the app is opened.

So my question is, is it possible to "wake" our app on a schedule to start a background upload?

Comment: Background fetch is your best option; You can certainly use it to upload as well as download.  You are right, though, you don't have any control over when it is scheduled.

Comment: So I suppose we should go with Background Fetch being the primary upload mechanism, and have it supplemented by a foreground upload when (if) the user opens the app and we have crossed a predefined threshold of data sitting in CoreData waiting to be uploaded. Is there a way to determine if Background Fetch has been disabled? If we could check that perhaps we could switch strategies.

Comment: Just answered my own question: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622994-backgroundrefreshstatus

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the Background fetch again and I believe it can solve your problem.

Look into [Selene](https://github.com/linkedin/Selene) Library on how to run periodic tasks.

and also glance through [how to run code when your app is terminated](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-when-your-app-is-terminated)

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look through both of those. I was reading somewhere that Background Fetch was limited to download, but also that you're provided 30 seconds to perform the fetch. Do you know any way to extend this, I suspect if we're uploading a large amount of data and the user is on a slow internet connection we may need more than 30 seconds.

Comment: You can use `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)` to get more time.

Comment: ok awesome! so when the system invokes `application(_:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)` I can use `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)` to perform the upload and immediately finish the Background fetch (before the upload is actually complete) with `completionHandler(.newData)`? If so that sounds like the app will satisfy the 30 sec requirement and not get 'punished' and be scheduled less.